# What exactly did Ant-Man see that made him say that their plan worked?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, when Dr. Banner did the snap to bring everyone back, we see Ant-Man looking outside and saying

> Guys... I think it worked!

<sub>[Script Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=avengers-endgame)</sub>

But **what exactly did he see that made him say that?** There were just a tree and a few birds outside.

Comment: I think it's Scott being his over-eager & casual self noticing a few birds & mentioning that it worked in a half joking way.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The snap affected all creatures in the universe including birds, Scott is looking at the birds and realising they have come back and so he works out that the "un-snap" has worked.

> **Natasha:** Thanos did what he planned to do, killed half of all living creatures in the universe.

There's nothing more to it than that.

---

To explain this further the facility was pretty devoid of life in the previous scenes and all of a sudden after the un-snap a bunch of birds are around. Seems pretty clear that the un-snap has at least partially worked. On top of that Clint's phone has started ringing in the background before Scott speaks and he probably heard his reaction to it.

Both things combined with Scott's nature to jump the gun seem like a reasonable interpretation of the events that it did in fact work.

Comment: No way. The life cycle of most birds is less than 5 years, thus in 5 years the bird population was already back to normal.
Sorry I was trying to make any sense of this film.

Comment: @Pierre Population would be back to normal yeah, but still another 50% would get added at that point. Even in-universe Scott jumping to conclusions because he sees more birds seems... not impossible?

Comment: @DavidMulder : yeah possibly. Or maybe a bird appeared halfway through a recently built wall? Or 200 people appeared 10km into the sky 5 years after the plane crashed? BTW I wonder how the people can reappear with clothes on anyway. Maybe he saw thousands of nudists? I'm really bad at watching films :D

Comment: @Pierre that's not how it works.  Their population (same as humans or any other animal) will be largely governed by not just the reproductive rate - deathrate; but also the food supply.  If you kill off half the life on earth; the things that produce a significant amount of food for birds and insects - trees - will also be dead.
They have a very slow growth rate.

in 5 years; you might have some sign of recovery; but frankly you're more likely to have had mass extinctions.

Comment: @UKMonkey : That's not how it works. In the food chain, the lower you get, the higher the reproduction rate, & the faster the life cycle. Sure trees won't recover fastly, but herbs will recover and take the room left by trees within a couple of months; giving enough food for the insects to recover. Half the predator population, same food amount, that's definitely a population bloom for insects! They can recover beyond previous population within a year, thus providing plenty of food for the remaining birds. Who have lost half their predators, too. Yes birds will definitely be back to normal.

Comment: @Pierre Demonstrably false.  Look at any of the woodland that humans have cut down and now is irreparably gone. Any rapid change of eco system is going to lead to things being wiped out.

Comment: @UKMonkey : any evidence to show that the forest "irreparably gone" are not covered in grasses within the year? Surely the centennial trees won't be back right away... And BTW removing half of the trees does not mean removing every single one of them and burning the smaller branches all over the place, thus killing any shrub.

Comment: @Pierre I'm pretty sure the Snap doesn't kill half of the trees. That said do you two fancy taking this to chat or elsewhere so I stop getting pinged about it?

Answer (score 5):

As I remember correctly, earlier in the movie he, or someone to him, said, that the world is too quiet without half of the birds. And it could be a reference to that.

Comment: If you can find that reference it might make this a proper answer.

Comment: Wasn't that about seeing whales in Hudson due to less boats that Steve mentions to Natasha. I have seen the movie several times & can't recall this birds thing

Comment: I wonder if this line was only in your local translation? It certainly wasn't in the the English version.